# How to find a minimal distance in array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, distance

Input is **sorted** array of integers, and I have to find minimal distance between the number |a.[i] - a.[j]| and a given number d.  How to find minimal distance?

```
distance = ||a.[i]-a.[j]| - d|
```

Comment: This needs more background, obviously. No general answer can be given. **You don't even ask a question**-

Comment: Think binary search :)

Comment: A question is: how to find the minimal distance?

Comment: Are you aware of how to find lower and upper bounds?

Comment: I don't know how to find these lower and upper bounds.

Comment: I will google it, now

Comment: a[j]=a[i]+d. For every a[i], find the closest a[j] possible (use upper and lower bounds concept). This can be done using binary search. Do this for all a[i] and keep calculating min distance everytime. That should do it

Comment: I was said to do it in linear time.

Comment: nope, I just train for my final exam at university.

Comment: Linear time? Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: @AmadeuszIwanowski Take advantege of sortedness. You are supposed to use imperative structure that is array (not lists) and use BinSearch algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks quite easy to do in linear time. Given the geneal puzzlement in some of the comments, I may be missing something which makes my solution useless. In any case, here I go:

```
I know this looks much like Java, however it's intended to be pseudocode.

Array is a, array size is n, array elements are a[0] to a[n-1]
Target distance is d, assumed non-negative

i=0;
j=0;
solutionI = 0;
solutionJ = 0;
minError = d;

while (j < n)
{
  error = abs(a[j]-a[i]-d)  // abs is absolute value
  if (error < minError)
  {
    solutionI = i;
    solutionJ = j;
    minError = error;
  }

  if (a[j] - a[i] <= d)
  {
    // Gap between a[i] and a[j] is too short, increase j to increase gap
    // Note we also advance j when we have an exact match
    // This is to keep always j>=i even when d=0
    j++;
  }
  else
  {
    // Gap between a[i] and a[j] is too long, increase i to decrease gap
    i++;
  }
}

Now solutionI and solutionJ mark the closest match to gap d
Also, minError tells how far we are from target distance d
```